# Problem with the integral representation of a function of the Bessel family

Tags: complex-analysis, bessel-functions

Consider the function defined by:
\begin{equation}
G_\mu(z, \psi) = i\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin( u + \psi) - i  \mu u},
\end{equation}
where $z$ and $\psi$ are real variables and $\mu$ a non-integer complex constant. The function is obviously periodic in $\psi$ of period $2\pi$, so:
\begin{equation}
 G_\mu(z, \psi) =  
 G_\mu(z, \psi + 2\pi) = 
 i\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mu i}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin( u + \psi + 2\pi) - i  \mu (u + 2\pi)} = 
 i\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mu i}\int_{2\pi}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\lambda\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin( \lambda + \psi) - i  \mu \lambda} = 
 \mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mu i}\left( G_\mu(z, \psi) - i\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\lambda\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin( \lambda + \psi) - i  \mu \lambda}\right).
\end{equation}
Hence $G_\mu(z,\psi)$ can also be represented as:
\begin{equation}
 G_\mu(z, \psi) =  \frac{\pi\mathrm{e}^{\pi \mu i}}{\sin\pi \mu}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{2\pi}\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin( \lambda + \psi) - i  \mu \lambda}.
\end{equation}
It is not difficult to show by simple algebraic manipulations that
\begin{equation}
 G_\mu(z, 0) =  \frac{\pi\mathrm{e}^{\pi \mu i}}{\sin\pi \mu}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{2\pi}\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin \lambda - i  \mu \lambda} =
\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi \mu} \mathbf{J}_\mu(z),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{J}_\mu(z) = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\pi}\,\cos(\mu\lambda - z \sin \lambda )
\end{equation}
is the Anger function (see [DLMF 11.10.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10.E1)).

On the other hand, starting from the original definition of $G_\mu(z,\psi)$ we have:
\begin{equation}
G_\mu(z, 0) = i\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{e}^{-i z \sin u - i  \mu u} = 
\int_0^{i\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-z \sinh t -  \mu t} = 
\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-z \sinh t -  \mu t},
\end{equation}
where in the last passage I've exploited Cauchy's theorem and the fact that the integrand is an entire function of $t$ for changing the integration path into the positive real line. This should be legitimate as long as $z>0$ and $\mathrm{Re}(\mu t) > 0$, since in that case the integrand calculated on the portion of circle at infinity enclosing the first quadrant of the complex $t$ plane vanishes.
Now, using the Schlaefli integral representation of the Bessel function $J_\mu(z)$ (valid for generic $\mu$), namely (see [DLMF 10.9.6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E6)):
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bessel-schlaefli-integral}
 J_{\mu}(z) = \mathbf{J}_\mu(z) - \frac{\sin\pi\mu}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-z\sinh t - \mu t}.
\end{equation}
It apparently comes out that:
\begin{equation}
G_\mu(z, 0) =  \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi \mu}(\mathbf{J}_\mu(z) - J_{\mu}(z)).
\end{equation}
I'm pretty sure that
\begin{equation}
G_\mu(z, 0) = \frac{\pi}{\sin\pi \mu} \mathbf{J}_\mu(z)
\end{equation}
is correct - it can be demonstrated by other means - so there's something wrong with my second argument, but I can't figure out where the error is.
Any hint?

By the way, in [DLMF 11.10.4](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10.E4) the same integral appearing in my calculations (as well as in the Schlaefli representation) is taken as the definition of the Anger-Weber function $\mathbf{A}_\mu(z)$, namely:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}_\mu(z) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\pi}\,\mathrm{e}^{-z \sinh t -  \mu t}.
\end{equation}
The Anger-Weber function is usually defined as (see e.g. ["Theory of Incomplete Cylindrical Functions and their Applications", M.M. Agrest and M.S. Maksimov"](https://books.google.it/books?id=WSTwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=incomplete%20anger%20function&source=bl&ots=QQP7apYMZb&sig=ACfU3U27K5gEObxwmkI2uhb30camVhTdnQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyrdT174LwAhVOPewKHYi6CgcQ6AEwBnoECAgQAw#v=onepage&q=incomplete%20anger%20function&f=false)):
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}_\mu(z) = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\pi}\,\mathrm{e}^{iz \sin\lambda -  i\mu \lambda} = \mathbf{J}_\mu(z) - i \mathbf{E}_\mu(z),
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{E}_\mu(z)$ is the Weber function:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_\mu(z) = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\lambda}{\pi}\,\sin(\mu\lambda - z \sin \lambda ).
\end{equation}
I can't manage to reconcile the two definitions, but I suspect this is strictly related to my problem. Also in this case, any hint is welcome.

Comment: It is better to use $\mathbf{J}_\mu(z)$ for the Anger function. The notation $A_\mu(z)$ (or rather $\mathbf{A}_\mu(z)$) is used for the associated Anger–Weber function (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10.i).

Comment: Yes, I know, I simply didn't know how to make the bold symbol...

Comment: Write \mathbf{J}.

Comment: Dear Gary, thank you. Since you cited DLMF, please have a look at the additional comment I appended at the end of my post. Maybe you can help me on that respect.

Comment: The two definitions you provided for $\mathbf{A}_\mu$ are clearly defining different functions. The first one is real for real $z>0$ and real $\mu$, the second one is non-real complex valued.

Comment: You've shown that
$$\left( \int_0^{i \infty} - \int_0^\infty \right) e^{-\mu t - z \sinh t} dt =
\pi \csc(\pi \mu) J_\mu(z)$$
for $\operatorname {Re} z > 0 \land \operatorname {Im} \mu < 0$.

Comment: Dear Maxim, thank you for your comment. I agree, of course, but I can't manage to get convinced of this result. If it were true, then
\begin{equation}
J_\mu(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi\mu)}{\pi}\int_C \mathrm{e}^{-z\sinh t - \mu t},
\end{equation}
where $C$ is the circular arc at infinity connecting $\infty$ to $i \infty$. But isn't the integrand vanishing on such a path?